# RAILS - ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - Possible issue with how array is being stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm getting a missing attribute error when trying to automatically create a InvoiceAppCollection when an Invoice is created.

This is the error that I'm getting:
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in InvoicesController#create

can't write unknown attribute `app_collection_id`

From what I've looked up when other people have this issue it has to do with the relationships between the models, but I'm pretty sure that I have the models communicating to each other properly.

The function I wrote to create the invoice app collection is in the invoice controller

```
def create_invoice_app_collection    
    InvoiceAppCollection.create(
      po_number: @invoice.po_number,
      app_collection: @invoice.app_collection
    )
  end
```

Here are my models and controllers. I also have the select box where the app_collections are being selected at the bottom.

Here are the Models

```
class AppCollection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  acts_as_tenant(:company)
  has_many :invoice_app_collections
  has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_app_collections
  
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  acts_as_tenant(:company)  
  has_many :invoice_app_collections
  has_many :app_collections, through: :invoice_app_collections

  validates :expiration, on: [:create, :update, :save], :presence => true
end

class InvoiceAppCollection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app_collection
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :company
  acts_as_tenant(:company)    

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :app_collection
end
```

AppCollectionController

```
class AppCollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_app_collection, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def index
    AppCollections = app_collection.all
  end

  def create
    @app_collection = app_collection.new(app_collection_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @app_collection.save
        format.html { redirect_to app_collection_url(@app_collection), notice: "App collection was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @app_collection }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @app_collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @app_collection.update(app_collection_params)
        format.html { redirect_to app_collection_url(@app_collection), notice: "App collection was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @app_collection }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @app_collection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @app_collection.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to app_collections_url, notice: "app collection was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_app_collection
      @app_collection = app_collection.find(params[:id])
    end

    def app_collection_params
      params.require(:app_collection).permit(:app_collection_type_id, :name, :company_id)
    end
end
```

InvoicesController

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  prepend_before_action :set_tenant
  after_action :create_invoice_app_collection, only: [:create, :update]

  def new
    @invoice_app_collection = Invoice.new
  end
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to invoice_url(@invoice), notice: "Invoice was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to invoice_url(@invoice), notice: "Invoice was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private

  def set_invoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  end

  def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:company_id, :po_number, :amount, :expiration, {:app_collection_id => []} )
  end

  def create_invoice_app_collection
    InvoiceAppCollection.create(
      po_number: @invoice.po_number,
      app_collection: @invoice.app_collection
    )
  end
end
```

InvoiceAppCollectionsController

```
class InvoiceAppCollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice_app_collection, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  prepend_before_action :set_tenant
  
  def new
    @invoice_app_collection = InvoiceAppCollection.new
  end
  private
  def set_invoice_app_collection
    @invoice_app_collection = InvoiceAppCollection.find(params[:id])
  end

  def invoice_app_collection_params
    params.require(:invoice_app_collection).permit(:company_id, :po_number, {:app_collection => []} )
  end

end
```

App Collection being set in the invoice form

```
<div>
  <%= form.label :app_collection, style: "display: block" %>
  <label> Select multiple app collections by holding the command key </label>
  <%= form.select :app_collection, options_for_select(app_collection.all.map {|a| [a.name, a.name]}),{include_blank: false} , class:"form-select", multiple: true %>
</div>
```

Schema

```
  create_table "app_collections", charset: "latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "app_collection_type_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "invoice_app_collections", charset: "latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.string "po_number"
    t.string "app_collection"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "invoices", charset: "latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.string "po_number"
    t.decimal "amount", precision: 10
    t.datetime "expiration"
    t.string "app_collection"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

I believe that the issue is that the app_collection is an array that gets sent to InvoiceAppController so I set it to an array in both controllers and that hasn't fixed it. I also allowed InvoiceAppCollection to accept nested attribues for app_collection but that also isn't fixing it.

I'm not really sure how to resolve this error so any guidance would be very appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a small problem, you wrote: `@invoice.app_collection`, but as your Invoice model is:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :app_collections, through: :invoice_app_collections
end
```

The code will look for relation `belongs_to :app_collection`, it required column `app_collection_id` in your Invoice model, which is not correct in this many-to-many between Invoice and AppCollection. Btw, I think this part `{:app_collection_id => []}` of `invoice_params` could raise error when this code `Invoice.new(invoice_params)`  is executed
My suggestion, to update the many-to-many relation:

```
@invoice.app_collections = AppCollection.where(id: params[:app_collection_ids]) // maybe you will want to update the params structure
@invoice.save
```

This code will auto-generate correspondant InvoiceAppCollection records.